# Elixir: Nebulex (Caching library) error

Tags: caching, erlang, elixir

I'm new to Elixir, trying to use Nebulex for making a simple local cache (Panda.Cache). I followed [its tutorial](https://hexdocs.pm/nebulex/getting-started.html) but finally, by doing these commands:

```
data = %{id: 1, text: "hello"}
Mycache.set(data[:id], data)
```

I get this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup_element(Panda.Cache, :metadata, 2)
    (nebulex) lib/nebulex/adapters/local/metadata.ex:19: Nebulex.Adapters.Local.Metadata.get/1
    (nebulex) lib/nebulex/adapters/local.ex:177: Nebulex.Adapters.Local.set/4
    (panda) lib/panda/cache.ex:2: Panda.Cache.execute/2
```

`Panda` is the name of my Elixir app and `Panda.Cache` the name of the cache I'm trying to make.

Any help or solution would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Update:

Project folders and files are like:

```
panda
    config
       config.exs
    lib
       panda.ex
       panda
           application.ex
           cache.ex
```

config.exs file:

```
use Mix.Config

config :panda, Panda.Cache,
  adapter: Nebulex.Adapters.Local,
  gc_interval: 86_400 # 24 hrs
```

cache.ex file:

```
defmodule Panda.Cache do
  use Nebulex.Cache, otp_app: :panda
end
```

application.ex file:

```
defmodule Panda.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    children = [
      supervisor(Panda.Cache, [])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Panda.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

And, how I tried to use the cache in my code:

```
defmodule Panda do


  def mytest do
    data = %{id: 1, text: "hello"}

    Panda.Cache.set(data[:id], data)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the cache module you created (the one called `Blog.Cache` in the tutorial)?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial step by step?

Comment: @Dogbert I've updated my question with the code.

Comment: @YongHaoHu Yes, check the question again please, I've updated it with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code in GitHub (https://github.com/ab00zar/FirstElixirCode), in the `mix.exs` file you are missing the app module, currently it is like this:

```
def application do
  [
    extra_applications: [:logger]
  ]
end
```

But it should be like this:

```
def application do
  [
    extra_applications: [:logger],
    mod: {Panda.Application, []}
  ]
end
```

Because of this, your app (and supervision tree) it is not being started and the cache (Nebulex) is started as part of your supervision tree. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. It works! As I found, it's a callback function that will be invoked when the application starts. Am I right? I wrote in my comments of another answer that it might be problem with the supervisor or process who is in charge of running the Cache but I didn't know how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you posted, but I cannot replicate the error.

When something like this happens I often do the following:

```
mix deps.clean --all
mix clean
mix deps.get
mix deps.compile
mix compile
```

and then I try again.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me! Did it work for you when you tried it with my code?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi Yes, it worked. I used the same code you're using. Maybe it has to do with the version of the library or the version of Elixir you're using. I tried with Elixir 1.4.5 and in my mix file I put `{:nebulex, "~> 1.0.0-rc.2"}` as the tutorial states.

Comment: How can I force my app to use this version? Even when I put this version in deps, it fetches ...rc.3 and not ...rc.2!!

Comment: @AboozarRajabi You are right! My mistake! It's downloading the "rc.3" as well for me. What Elixir and Erlang versions do you have installed? I have 1.4.5 for Elixir and 20 for Erlang.

Comment: Elixir 1.6.4 (compiled with OTP 20) and Erlang/OTP 20! It's strange! It should work! It might be a problem with running Supervisor (or process which is in charge of) in runtime. No?

Comment: And let me know please if you know a better solution to be used as a Cache for Elixir

Comment: Could you let me know please how do you run your app after doing these steps?